# 90 degrees angle smooth

Tags: modeling

I've got a model. [image]

It's shaded smooth in object mode (+ autosmooth). So everything's ok, but I need to smooth several 90 degrees angles. 3 angle is smooth, 2nd is not, the first one needs to be smooth too. How can I do that?

upd: [image: img]

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like 3 has a bevel, but the others do not have the same bevel.
Try selecting the 90 degree edges and applying a bevel (ctrl B).

Comment: If I separate mesh I can do this for 90 degree angle (autosmooth off, picture updated). Shaded smooth only several faces in edit mode, not whole object. But I have to keep this whole details as one object for UV, so I need shade smooth whole object and these several 90 degree angles

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>  to bevel if that's what you mean by smooth. 
Make sure to apply scale beforehand